# I get an error in the In-App Billing example (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I want to make an example with an Activity that only subscribers can see. I would like to use the Google in-app billing library for this. I tried to move forward using Google documents, but I encountered a problem.

'''
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener{

```
private BillingClient billingClient;
String vipUpgradeOnePrice, vipUpgradeTwoPrice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    billingClient=BillingClient.newBuilder(MainActivity.this).setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode()== BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WORK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DISCONECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    List<String> skuList=new ArrayList<>();
    skuList.add("vip_upgrade_one");
    skuList.add("vip_upgrade_two");

    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params=SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

                    //Process the Result
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode()== BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null){
                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList){

                            String sku=skuDetails.getSku();
                            String price=skuDetails.getPrice();

                            if ("jadevip_upgrade_one".equals(sku)){
                                vipUpgradeOnePrice = price;
                            }else if ("jadevip_upgrade_two".equals(sku)){
                                vipUpgradeTwoPrice=price;
                            }

                            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                    .build();
                            int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this,billingFlowParams);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

    if (billingResult.getResponseCode()== BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
        && purchases !=null){
        for (Purchase purchase:purchases){
            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }
    }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode()== BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED){
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
    }else {
        // Handle any other error codes.
    }

}

BillingClient client=BillingClient.newBuilder(MainActivity.this).setListener(this).build();
AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Purchase acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {

    if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        // Grant entitlement to the user.

        // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();
            client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
        }
    }
}
```

}
'''

This is where I got the error. It says that there is a type error in the error description and the responseCode cannot be an int type. I don't get any errors when I write reponseCod in BillingResult type but this time it doesn't work.

```
int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this,billingFlowParams);
```

I will be very grateful if anyone knows how to fix the error.

Finally, since my goal is to prepare an Activity that only subscribers can see, do I need to write these codes into the setOnClickListener method of the button to switch to the Activity? Or is it enough to write only part of it?

Answer (score 0):

`billingClient.launchBillingFlow()` returns `BillingResult`:

```
BillingResult responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this,billingFlowParams);
```

Here's API reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient

Comment: Yes, I actually wrote BillingResult first, but the application didn't work. Since the example in Google documents is written in the type int, I also wrote in the type int. So both kinds of applications do not work. I wonder where I am wrong ?

Comment: what kind of error (copy / paste) you get when using `BillingResult` ?